# return AJAX callback return

Tags: javascript, ajax

For example I have a function:

```
var f1 = function(arg) {
    var a;
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(data) {
            a = f2(data);
            //return a;
        }
    });
    //return a;
}

var f3 = function() {
    a = f1(arg);
}
```

How can I return `a` after AJAX get `data` in `f1`?

Comment: where do you want to send a. that is the important question

Comment: It's **A**JAX... you need to make your code work using callback functions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't return the result of your ajax request since the request is asynchronous (and synchronous ajax requests are a **terrible** idea).

Your best bet will be to pass your own callback into f1

```
var f1 = function(arg, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        success: function(data) {
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Then you'd call `f1` like this:

```
f1(arg, function(data) { 
           var a = f2(data);
           alert(a);
        }
 );
```

Comment: What does f2 represent? maybe the callback?

Comment: It's ok, this explains it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754619/jquery-ajax-success-callback-function-definition

Comment: I know in c# you have the async and await commands with Tasks. I do not think you can do this in JS. If you can, either do the callback like the other people say on here. However, if you use webpack or some ES(whatever it is at now) compiler, then you can use promises. This is a great FREE resource for a lot of the new stuff in ES(6) http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_promises.html

Answer (score 1):

Short, easy answer: you can't.

You *could* make `a` a global, but you're subject to timing issues.

Better to either:

1. Pass in a callback to run in the Ajax success, or
2. Use jQuery's [`.when`/`.then` construct](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/), or
3. Just do the work in the callback.
4. *(Yeah, you could make the call synchronous. Please don't.)*

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this is to make the ajax call synchronous. Meaning in your f1 function setup the ajax call with async: false so that the function doesn't move on until the call is completed and the data returned.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to need to make the ajax call synchronous. You can do that like this:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  async: false,
  success: ...
});
return a;
```

This way the JS execution will pause until the call returns and the `success` function runs.

Of course there is the issue of sync calls. It's best if you refactor your code so that you do what you need to do with the `a` variable in the `success` callback.

Building on this idea, suppose your `f3` function was something like this:

```
var f3 = function() {
  a = f1(arg);
  alert(a); //i.e. "do something" with "a"
}
```

You could do this instead:

```
var f3 = function() {
  f1(arg);
}
var f3_callback = function(a) {
  alert(a); //i.e. "do something" with "a"
}
```

So, your success function would look like this:

```
success: function(data) {
  a = f2(data);
  f3_callback(a);
}
```

I hope this is clear!