# jQuery: load() loads the page but doesn't focus the textbox

Tags: jquery

I have a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/SDr3F/10/

**Currently:**

onclick, it alerts

```
alert('hi')
```

**Required:**

onclick, it loads a `search.html` with a search text box and `focus` in textbox

*search.html*

```
<input id="search-input" type="text" class="input-medium search-query span4">
```

**How I set focus?**

```
$(function(){
  $("#search").click(function(){
      $('#feature').load('templates/search.html');
      $('#search-input').focus();
      alert("hi");
  });
});
```

**Problem**

- It loads the page BUT doesn't focuses inside textbox, how do I fix this?

Comment: and how do you set the focus on your desired element? `.focus()` ya?

Comment: updated, thank you for mentioning

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146801/ajax-post-or-get-wont-function-cannot-use-the-response for some insights on AJAX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example you focus element right after the Ajax request is made but not *when the request is successfully completed*. Hence, you try to focus the element that is not yet loaded.

You should add the [**complete**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) handler. The following should work:

```
$("#search").click(function() {
    $("#feature").load("templates/search.html", function() {
        $("#search-input").focus();
    });
});​
```

Comment: +1, but are you going to explain why it needs to be in a callback so that the OP knows for next time?

Comment: Awesome, thanks much, I tried with callback before but it didn't work(I am sure, I did not do it correctly), but yeah, why it needs to be in callback?

Comment: @daydreamer The Ajax request works asynchronously. The callback will be executed when all the content from "search.html" is loaded, and with that you can do the element focusing. Otherwise, the "search-input" element won't exist.

Answer (score 2):

You need a callback so that it knows that the content of the page is fully loaded before it tries to set the focus.