# JavaScript get JSON from rest API without re-rendering the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rest

### Problem

I'm trying to query a rest API in javascript and use jQuery to parse and insert the results into my webpage. When the query is made I believe it submits the search form and re-renders the page thus removing all of the elements I just queried and inserted.

#### *Is there away to get a JSON object from a rest api and not re-render the webpage?*

Here's what I'm using to make my requests:

```
function get_data(){
    var url = "www.rest_api/search_term&apikey=My_Key"
    var xmlHttp = null;
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", url, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

The search term comes from a simple input form, and is submitted when the submit button is clicked. My goal is to keep this webpage to a single page and avoid a results page.

#### What I've tried

[I can't return my json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718904/i-cant-return-my-json-object)

[Get JSON data from external URL and display it in a div as plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922101/get-json-data-from-external-url-and-display-a-particular-value-by-injecting-it-i)

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Request URL example:

http://woof.magnify.net/api/content/find?vq=karma&per_page=5&page=1&sort=popularity&key=84LTHNZQ1364W14D&format=json

Comment: it all depends - does the api support JSONP?

Comment: Just stop using a form that reloads the page when submitted and stick with the ajax call ?

Comment: @adeneo so far I've been able to do that by always returning false at the end of my functions but I cant seem to get around submitting the page when I use a function to get the json.

Comment: @NeilS I found that it does support JSONP from the documentation.

Comment: add `event.preventDefault()` to the click event on the button, or `onclick='functionName();return false;'`

Comment: Thanks, @abc123 but I'm already using `return false;` on the click event. This `get_data()` function is in a separate script thats called by the click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember when calling jsonp apis, you have to add an additional parameter to the url : `callback=?`

here's a simple fiddle as an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8DXxN/

Comment: Thanks for the answer Neil. I've been trying to play with the call backs but couldnt quite get it to work. How would I return the data to manipulate it? I've tried: `function (data) {return data;});` but it errors and says I should use a post request.

Comment: the data is represented by an json object, and that's why in my fiddle I used JSON.stringify to convert the data object to a string. Where are you getting the errors? in jsfiddle? or on your own environment?

Comment: In the fiddle and in my local environment. http://jsfiddle.net/8DXxN/1/ Error: `{"error": "Please use POST request"}` Same issue when I return `JSON.stringify(data);`

Comment: in that example, you're returning a data object in the success callback function. You should be manipulating the DOM to insert the data in that function, not returning an unmolested object.

Comment: here's a good tutorial about inserting data from a ajax request: http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/jQuery-AJAX-and-JSON-P969.html

Comment: Thanks for your help and the tutorial link. I was so fixated on getting the data out of the function that I never realized I didnt have too.